# Sumo Logic: _sourceCategory vs cluster

Tags: sumologic

With Sumo Logic, what is the difference between 'cluster' and '_sourceCategory'?

I've tried looking at the documentation but am not finding anything for cluster itself. If you know, please share the knowledge.

Comment: Could you share a query where you're using "cluster"? That isn't a keyword or operator in Sumo Logic, so it must be specific to your environment.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like cluster in sumo logic. 
It is `_sourceCategory` and `_sourceHost`. 
`_sourceCategory` basically just means the name of categories to which these logs belong. For example: If you are ingesting logs of a service named X, you can put its  _sourceCategory as X and then search for it with query `_sourceCategory=X`

If you cluster name is Y and your nodes are numbered Y-1,Y-2 ... Y-10, then you can search it like `_sourceHost=Y*`. This would give you all the logs for cluster Y.